# Need help making swift structs from Json

Tags: swiftui

This is my data: https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/complete?lat=60.46167&lon=10.7787&altitude=0

And this is my structs below. In DataClass I can access anything inside "instant", but not "next12hours", "next1hours" and "next6hours". They are all nil. Why? There is no error messages from the decoder.

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Welcome
struct RootYr: Codable {
    let type: String?
    let geometry: Geometry?
    let properties: Properties?
}

// MARK: - Geometry
struct Geometry: Codable {
    let type: String?
    let coordinates: [Double]?
}

// MARK: - Properties
struct Properties: Codable {
    let meta: Meta?
    let timeseries: [Timesery]?
}

// MARK: - Meta
struct Meta: Codable {
    let updatedAt: String?
    let units: Units?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
        case units
    }
}

// MARK: - Units
struct Units: Codable {
    let airPressureAtSeaLevel, airTemperature, airTemperatureMax, airTemperatureMin: String?
    let airTemperaturePercentile10, airTemperaturePercentile90, cloudAreaFraction, cloudAreaFractionHigh: String?
    let cloudAreaFractionLow, cloudAreaFractionMedium, dewPointTemperature, fogAreaFraction: String?
    let precipitationAmount, precipitationAmountMax, precipitationAmountMin, probabilityOfPrecipitation: String?
    let probabilityOfThunder, relativeHumidity, ultravioletIndexClearSky, windFromDirection: String?
    let windSpeed, windSpeedOfGust, windSpeedPercentile10, windSpeedPercentile90: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case airPressureAtSeaLevel = "air_pressure_at_sea_level"
        case airTemperature = "air_temperature"
        case airTemperatureMax = "air_temperature_max"
        case airTemperatureMin = "air_temperature_min"
        case airTemperaturePercentile10 = "air_temperature_percentile_10"
        case airTemperaturePercentile90 = "air_temperature_percentile_90"
        case cloudAreaFraction = "cloud_area_fraction"
        case cloudAreaFractionHigh = "cloud_area_fraction_high"
        case cloudAreaFractionLow = "cloud_area_fraction_low"
        case cloudAreaFractionMedium = "cloud_area_fraction_medium"
        case dewPointTemperature = "dew_point_temperature"
        case fogAreaFraction = "fog_area_fraction"
        case precipitationAmount = "precipitation_amount"
        case precipitationAmountMax = "precipitation_amount_max"
        case precipitationAmountMin = "precipitation_amount_min"
        case probabilityOfPrecipitation = "probability_of_precipitation"
        case probabilityOfThunder = "probability_of_thunder"
        case relativeHumidity = "relative_humidity"
        case ultravioletIndexClearSky = "ultraviolet_index_clear_sky"
        case windFromDirection = "wind_from_direction"
        case windSpeed = "wind_speed"
        case windSpeedOfGust = "wind_speed_of_gust"
        case windSpeedPercentile10 = "wind_speed_percentile_10"
        case windSpeedPercentile90 = "wind_speed_percentile_90"
    }
}

// MARK: - Timesery
struct Timesery: Codable {
    let time: String?
    let data: DataClass?
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let instant: Instant?
    let next12_Hours: Next12_Hours?
    let next1Hours: Next1_Hours?
    let next6_Hours: Next6_Hours?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case instant
        case next12_Hours = "next_12_hours"
        case next1Hours = "next_1_hours"
        case next6_Hours = "next_6_hours"
    }
}

// MARK: - Instant
struct Instant: Codable {
    let details: InstantDetails? //[String: Double]? 
}

// MARK: - InstantDetails
struct InstantDetails: Codable {
    let airPressureAtSeaLevel: Double?
    let airTemperature: Double?
    let airTemperaturePercentile10: Double?
    let airTemperaturePercentile90: Double?
    let cloudAreaFraction: Double?
    let cloudAreaFractionHigh: Double?
    let cloudAreaFractionLow: Double?
    let cloudAreaFractionMedium: Double?
    let dewPointTemperature: Double?
    let fogAreaFraction: Double?
    let relativeHumidity: Double?
    let ultravioletIndexClearSky: Double?
    let windFromDirection: Double?
    let windSpeed: Double?
    let windSpeedOfGusts: Double?
    let windSpeedPercentile10: Double?
    let windSpeedPercentile90: Double?
}
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case airPressureAtSeaLevel = "air_pressure_at_sea_level"
    case airTemperature = "air_temperature"
    case airTemperaturePercentile10 = "air_temperature_percentile_10"
    case airTemperaturePercentile90 = "air_temperature_percentile_90"
    case cloudAreaFraction = "cloud_area_fraction"
    case cloudAreaFractionHigh = "cloud_area_fraction_high"
    case cloudAreaFractionLow = "cloud_area_fraction_low"
    case cloudAreaFractionMedium = "cloud_area_fraction_medium"
    case dewPointTemperature = "dew_point_temperature"
    case fogAreaFraction = "fog_area_fraction"
    case relativeHumidity = "relative_humidity"
    case ultravioletIndexClearSky = "ultraviolet_index_clear_sky"
    case windFromDirection = "wind_from_direction"
    case windSpeed = "wind_speed"
    case windSpeedOfGust = "wind_speed_of_gust"
    case windSpeedPercentile10 = "wind_speed_percentile_10"
    case windSpeedPercentile90 = "wind_speed_percentile_90"
}

// MARK: - Next12_Hours
struct Next12_Hours: Codable {
    let summary: Next12_HoursSummary?
    let details: Next12_HoursDetails?
}

// MARK: - Next12_HoursDetails
struct Next12_HoursDetails: Codable {
    let probabilityOfPrecipitation: Double?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case probabilityOfPrecipitation = "probability_of_precipitation"
    }
}

// MARK: - Next12_HoursSummary
struct Next12_HoursSummary: Codable {
    let symbolCode: SymbolCode?
    let symbolConfidence: SymbolConfidence?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case symbolCode = "symbol_code"
        case symbolConfidence = "symbol_confidence"
    }
}

enum SymbolCode: String, Codable {
    case clearskyday = "clearsky_day"
    case clearskynight = "clearsky_night"
    case clearskypolartwilight = "clearsky_polartwilight"
    case cloudy = "cloudy"
    case fairday = "fair_day"
    case fairnight = "fair_night"
    case fairpolartwilight = "fair_polartwilight"
    case fog = "fog"
    case heavyrain = "heavyrain"
    case heavyrainandthunder = "heavyrainandthunder"
    case heavyrainshowersandthunderday = "heavyrainshowersandthunder_day"
    case heavyrainshowersandthundernight = "heavyrainshowersandthunder_night"
    case heavyrainshowersandthunderpolartwilight = "heavyrainshowersandthunder_polartwilight"
    case heavyrainshowersday = "heavyrainshowers_day"
    case heavyrainshowersnight = "heavyrainshowers_night"
    case heavyrainshowerspolartwilight = "heavyrainshowers_polartwilight"
    case heavysleet = "heavysleet"
    case heavysleetandthunder = "heavysleetandthunder"
    case heavysleetshowersandthunderday = "heavysleetshowersandthunder_day"
    case heavysleetshowersandthundernight = "heavysleetshowersandthunder_night"
    case heavysleetshowersandthunderpolartwilight = "heavysleetshowersandthunder_polartwilight"
    case heavysleetshowersday = "heavysleetshowers_day"
    case heavysleetshowersnight = "heavysleetshowers_night"
    case heavysleetshowerspolartwilight = "heavysleetshowers_polartwilight"
    case heavysnowshowersandthunderday = "heavysnowshowersandthunder_day"
    case heavysnowshowersandthundernight = "heavysnowshowersandthunder_night"
    case heavysnowshowersandthunderpolartwilight = "heavysnowshowersandthunder_polartwilight"
    case heavysnowshowersday = "heavysnowshowers_day"
    case heavysnowshowersnight = "heavysnowshowers_night"
    case heavysnowshowerspolartwilight = "heavysnowshowers_polartwilight"
    case lightrainshowersandthunderday = "lightrainshowersandthunder_day"
    case lightrainshowersandthundernight = "lightrainshowersandthunder_night"
    case lightrainshowersandthunderpolartwilight = "lightrainshowersandthunder_polartwilight"
    case lightrainshowersday = "lightrainshowers_day"
    case lightrainshowersnight = "lightrainshowers_night"
    case lightrainshowerspolartwilight = "lightrainshowers_polartwilight"
    case lightsleetshowersday = "lightsleetshowers_day"
    case lightsleetshowersnight = "lightsleetshowers_night"
    case lightsleetshowerspolartwilight = "lightsleetshowers_polartwilight"
    case lightsnowshowersday = "lightsnowshowers_day"
    case lightsnowshowersnight = "lightsnowshowers_night"
    case lightsnowshowerspolartwilight = "lightsnowshowers_polartwilight"
    case lightssleetshowersandthunderday = "lightssleetshowersandthunder_day"
    case lightssleetshowersandthundernight = "lightssleetshowersandthunder_night"
    case lightssleetshowersandthunderpolartwilight = "lightssleetshowersandthunder_polartwilight"
    case lightssnowshowersandthunderday = "lightssnowshowersandthunder_day"
    case lightssnowshowersandthundernight = "lightssnowshowersandthunder_night"
    case lightssnowshowersandthunderpolartwilight = "lightssnowshowersandthunder_polartwilight"
    case partlycloudyday = "partlycloudy_day"
    case partlycloudynight = "partlycloudy_night"
    case partlycloudypolartwilight = "partlycloudy_polartwilight"
    case rainshowersandthunderday = "rainshowersandthunder_day"
    case rainshowersandthundernight = "rainshowersandthunder_night"
    case rainshowersandthunderpolartwilight = "rainshowersandthunder_polartwilight"
    case rainshowersday = "rainshowers_day"
    case rainshowersnight = "rainshowers_night"
    case rainshowerspolartwilight = "rainshowers_polartwilight"
    case sleetshowersandthunderday = "sleetshowersandthunder_day"
    case sleetshowersandthundernight = "sleetshowersandthunder_night"
    case sleetshowersandthunderpolartwilight = "sleetshowersandthunder_polartwilight"
    case sleetshowersday = "sleetshowers_day"
    case sleetshowersnight = "sleetshowers_night"
    case sleetshowerspolartwilight = "sleetshowers_polartwilight"
    case snowshowersandthunderday = "snowshowersandthunder_day"
    case snowshowersandthundernight = "snowshowersandthunder_night"
    case snowshowersandthunderpolartwilight = "snowshowersandthunder_polartwilight"
    case snowshowersday = "snowshowers_day"
    case snowshowersnight = "snowshowers_night"
    case snowshowerspolartwilight = "snowshowers_polartwilight"
    case heavysnow = "heavysnow"
    case heavysnowandthunder = "heavysnowandthunder"
    case lightrain = "lightrain"
    case lightrainandthunder = "lightrainandthunder"
    case lightsleet = "lightsleet"
    case lightsleetandthunder = "lightsleetandthunder"
    case lightsnow = "lightsnow"
    case lightsnowandthunder = "lightsnowandthunder"
    case rain = "rain"
    case rainandthunder = "rainandthunder"
    case sleet = "sleet"
    case sleetandthunder = "sleetandthunder"
    case snow = "snow"
    case snowandthunder = "snowandthunder"
}

enum SymbolConfidence: String, Codable {
    case certain = "certain"
    case somewhatCertain = "somewhat certain"
    case uncertain = "uncertain"
}

// MARK: - Next1_Hours
struct Next1_Hours: Codable {
    let summary: Next1_HoursSummary?
    let details: Next1_HoursDetails?
}

// MARK: - Next1_HoursDetails
struct Next1_HoursDetails: Codable {
    let precipitationAmount: Int?
    let precipitationAmountMax: Double?
    let precipitationAmountMin: Int?
    let probabilityOfPrecipitation, probabilityOfThunder: Double?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case precipitationAmount = "precipitation_amount"
        case precipitationAmountMax = "precipitation_amount_max"
        case precipitationAmountMin = "precipitation_amount_min"
        case probabilityOfPrecipitation = "probability_of_precipitation"
        case probabilityOfThunder = "probability_of_thunder"
    }
}

// MARK: - Next1_HoursSummary
struct Next1_HoursSummary: Codable {
    let symbolCode: SymbolCode?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case symbolCode = "symbol_code"
    }
}

// MARK: - Next6_Hours
struct Next6_Hours: Codable {
    let summary: Next1_HoursSummary?
    let details: Next6_HoursDetails?
}

// MARK: - Next6_HoursDetails
struct Next6_HoursDetails: Codable {
    let airTemperatureMax, airTemperatureMin, precipitationAmount, precipitationAmountMax: Double?
    let precipitationAmountMin, probabilityOfPrecipitation: Double?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case airTemperatureMax = "air_temperature_max"
        case airTemperatureMin = "air_temperature_min"
        case precipitationAmount = "precipitation_amount"
        case precipitationAmountMax = "precipitation_amount_max"
        case precipitationAmountMin = "precipitation_amount_min"
        case probabilityOfPrecipitation = "probability_of_precipitation"
    }
}
```

This is my swift code:

```
let urlYr = URL(string: "https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/complete?lat=\(vesselPosition.latitude)&lon=\(vesselPosition.longitude)&altitude=0")!
                let requestYr = URLRequest(url: urlYr)
                let (dataYr, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: requestYr)
                
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    let allDataYr = try decoder.decode(RootYr.self, from: dataYr)
                    
                    selectedVessel.weatherAirTemp = allDataYr.properties?.timeseries?[0].data?.instant?.details?.airTemperature //works fine
                    selectedVessel.weatherWindSpeed = allDataYr.properties?.timeseries?[0].data?.instant?.details?.windSpeed    //works fine
                    selectedVessel.weatherWindDirection = allDataYr.properties?.timeseries?[0].data?.instant?.details?.windFromDirection //works fine
                    selectedVessel.weatherSymbol = String(describing: allDataYr.properties?.timeseries![0].data?.next1Hours?.summary?.symbolCode)   //this one is nil
                    
                    print("\(String(describing: allDataYr.properties?.timeseries![0].data))")
                } catch {
                    print("Error decoding JSON from met.no: \(error)")
                }
```

Still nil no matter what I do..

Comment: The JSON you linked doesn’t have a property with named next12hours it’s next_12_hours. You can use CodingKeys to standardize your variables and compensate. Also remove the snake case strategy if you include CodingKeys that are already compensating

Comment: If i remove the convertFromSnakeCase I get: "Error decoding JSON from met.no: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Number 0.2 is not representable in Swift." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Number 0.2 is not representable in Swift.})))"

And I already have a coding key that maps next_12_hours to next12Hours, so I don't understand your answer. :) Bear with me, I'm very new to this..

Comment: You are duplicating work either let the strategy do the converting or do it yourself with CodingKeys. Stuff it getting missed because there are inconsistencies. Whichever way you pick you will have to handle each case individually. Such as the 0.2 error, you need a Double for those properties not a String. That is likely just your next error... Remove the strategy.

Comment: @Prebbe83 for readability, it is preferred to add additional code etc in the question, instead of the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickType.io is a great help for Decoding JSON but just as every other tool out there you need to understand what is going on.

QuickType does not use decoding strategies, their structs create `CodingKeys` for all the variables. Which is a perfectly acceptable way of doing things. But `keyDecodingStrategy` & `dateDecodingStrategy` help in creating much simpler models.

You should never use `CodingKeys` to decode snake case if the `keyDecodingStrategy` is being used because then you get into a tangle. Which is likely why you have everything marked as optional. I'm sure you got several errors saying it couldn't find keys.

If you keep the `keyDecodingStrategy`

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
```

get rid of ALL your `CodingKeys`.

Your `Instant` model will look something like

```
struct Instant: Codable {
    let details: Details
    
    struct Details: Codable {
        var relativeHumidity: Double
        var ultravioletIndexClearSky: Double?
        var windSpeed: Double
        var airTemperaturePercentile10: Double
        var fogAreaFraction: Double?
        var cloudAreaFractionMedium: Double
        var airTemperaturePercentile90: Double
        var windSpeedOfGust: Double?
        var airPressureAtSeaLevel: Double
        var cloudAreaFraction: Double
        var windSpeedPercentile90: Double
        var dewPointTemperature: Double
        var cloudAreaFractionHigh: Double
        var windFromDirection: Double
        var airTemperature: Double
        var cloudAreaFractionLow: Double
        var windSpeedPercentile10: Double
    }
}
```

You'll also have to adjust all the other little bugs you'll encounter because you are changing the approach such as your `DataClass`.

```
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let instant: Instant
    let next12Hours: Next12_Hours?
    let next1Hours: Next1_Hours?
    let next6Hours: Next6_Hours?
}
```

You should review the API's documentation to see what needs to be optional and what will never be optional.

https://api.met.no/doc/locationforecast/datamodel