Issue parsing JSON data
Recently, I am facing issue in parsing the JSON into the model class.
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "252",
            "user_id": "8004",
            "currency_iso_code": "INR",
            "currency_symbol": "\u20b9",
            "country_id": "3",
            "product_id": "5",
            "product_name": "Sun Remedy (afflicted Sun Pooja",
            "product_price": "1200.00",
            "service_category_id": "8",
            "service_category_name": "Puja Homam",
            "image_name": "https:\/\/testing.com\/writeable\/uploads\/20230809132517_item_service.jpg",
            "quantity": "3",
            "total_amount": "3600.00",
            "rating": "4",
            "item_price_id": "114"
        }
    ],
    "total_price_amount": "3600.00",
    "final_price_amount": "4248.00",
    "count": "1",
    "gst_data": [
        {
            "name": "igst",
            "value": "648.00"
        }
    ],
    "gst_percent": "18.00",
    "gst_amount": "648.00",
    "message": "API Accessed Successfully!"
}

For the above json response I have created this model class:
struct CartItem: Codable {
   let id: String
   let user_id: String
   let currency_iso_code: String
   let currency_symbol: String
   let country_id: String
   let product_id: String
   let product_name: String
   let product_price: String
   let service_category_id: String
   let service_category_name: String
   let image_name: String
   let quantity: String
   let total_amount: String
   let rating: String
   let item_price_id: String
}

struct CartGSTData: Codable {
    let name: String
    let value: String
}

struct CartResponseData: Codable {
    let status: Bool?
    let data: [CartItem]?
    let total_price_amount: String?
    let final_price_amount: String?
    let count: String?
    let gst_data: [CartGSTData]?
    let gst_percent: String?
    let gst_amount: String?
    let message: String?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.status = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .status)
        self.data = try container.decodeIfPresent([CartItem].self, forKey: .data)
        self.total_price_amount = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .total_price_amount)
        self.final_price_amount = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .final_price_amount)
        self.count = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .count)
        self.gst_data = try container.decodeIfPresent([CartGSTData].self, forKey: .gst_data)
        self.gst_percent = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .gst_percent)
        self.gst_amount = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .gst_amount)
        self.message = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .message)
    }
}

struct DeleteCartItemRequestEntity: Codable {
    var user_id: String?
    var cart_id: String?
}

While the parsing the value it's parsing in different key. Can see in this image for key's count and final_price_amount, the count key get parsed by final_price_amount value and final_price_amount didn't get parsed. For key gst_data also data is not parsed.

And this is json response in postman

Print the value in Console from code
CartResponseData(status: Optional(true), data: Optional([SuperAstrologer.CartItem(id: "252", user_id: "8004", currency_iso_code: "INR", currency_symbol: "₹", country_id: "3", product_id: "5", product_name: "Sun Remedy (afflicted Sun Pooja", product_price: "1200.00", service_category_id: "8", service_category_name: "Puja Homam", image_name: "https://stagging.superastrologer.com/writeable/uploads/20230809132517_item_service.jpg", quantity: "3", total_amount: "3600.00", rating: "4", item_price_id: "114")]), total_price_amount: Optional("3600.00"), final_price_amount: Optional("4248.00"), count: Optional("1"), gst_data: Optional([SuperAstrologer.CartGSTData(name: "igst", value: "648.00")]), gst_percent: Optional("18.00"), gst_amount: Optional("648.00"), message: Optional("API Accessed Successfully!"))

Did you try by printing the value in Console from code and not from Breakpoint as sometimes the values can be wrong (rarely, but sometimes)?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77679491/need-help-making-swift-structs-from-json/77679959#77679959

Hi @Larme, Yes it prints all value and I have added above.

@loremipsum I have added codingkey also but faing same issue.

Decoding decodeIfPresent into an optional is redundant. Delete init(from:) in CartResponseData. And – unrelated to the issue – get rid of the snake_case stuff with the .convertFromSnakeCase strategy
